# How to serialize kotlin sealed class with open val using kotlinx serialization

Tags: kotlin, serialization, kotlinx.serialization

```
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
sealed class Exercise(open val id: String) {

    @Serializable
    data class Theory(override val id: String) : Exercise(id)
}
```

I have such kind of sealed class in my code, and compiler says me:
`Serializable class has duplicate serial name of property 'id', either in the class itself or its supertypes`.

Is there way to have open val in serializable sealed class, which works correctly when overriding it?

Comment: Have you tried: `data class Theory(id: String):Exercise(id)` ?

Comment: I can't do so with data classes (because constructor must have only property (val / var) parameters), but even if I do it with `class Theory(id: String) : Exercise(id)` instead, I have this error:
`This class is not serializable automatically because it has primary constructor parameters that are not properties`

Answer (score 13):

This is [Kotlin issue KT-38958](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-38958). It seems to be a corner case of the [Constructor properties requirement](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/basic-serialization.md#constructor-properties-requirement).

It can be solved by using the following implementation,

```
import kotlinx.serialization.*
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json

@Serializable
sealed class Exercise {
    abstract val id: String

    @Serializable
    data class Theory(override val id: String) : Exercise()
}

fun main() {
    val t1 = Exercise.Theory("t1")
    val t1Json = Json.encodeToString(t1)
    println(t1Json)
    println(Json.decodeFromString<Exercise.Theory>(t1Json).toString())
}
```

which will output:

```
{"id":"t1"}
Theory(id=t1)
```

For details, see ["Designing serializable hierarchy"](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md#designing-serializable-hierarchy) in the Kotlin Serialization Guide.

Comment: In my case I cannot declare the val as `abstract` for some reason

Comment: With a class declared as `abstract` (or `sealed`, being a special form of `abstract`)?

Comment: Ah no I realized I was declaring it abstract in the primary constructor instead of the class body. Typical Kotlin mistake I do :D

Comment: Kudos to your details link :D, thanks. It is a must read

Answer (score 1):

Though `abstract` property is a great way to deal with this, you can also take advantage of `sealed interface` which helps solving this in a more concise way

```
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
sealed interface Exercise {
   val id: String

   @Serializable
   data class Theory(override val id: String) : Exercise
}
```